# Options method of the BitmapFactory is not recognized

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

When I tried to use the `options` of the `BitmapFactory` as follows:

`BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory().Options();` eclipse underscores the `options()` on the right hand side with red squiggle, despite all the required packages are imported. How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

Not

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory().Options();

Answer (score 2):

You where so close:

`BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();`

You want to instantiate the Options not the Factory

---

If if helps you make sense of it, you could also import the options

`import static android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options;`

```
    Options options = new Options();
```